# How can I include extensions in OpenCart 2.3 HTML module?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm new to OpenCart 2.3. On the home page layout, I've set the content-top to a slideshow module. Now I want the content-top to be a HTML Content module, where the HTML content will layout the slideshow module? Is there some sort of a hook for this?

Thanks

Comment: You can assign as many module as you want to your home page content-top, whats the problem?

Comment: I would like to layout the slider in such a way that the slider is on the left and some images to the right. Can I layout then the content-top in this manner?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) go to slideshow settings and define its width and height to what you need.
2) go to home page layout and assign slideshow module to content-top, then assign html content module to content-top
3) add `float` to slideshow module, here is an example:

```
#slideshow0 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 772px;
}
```

note that `#slideshow0` is for example, yours may be different. 
[image]